# Apache Beam SQL error in Python - ValueError: Unsupported type: Any

Tags: python, apache-beam, beam-sql

I wrote an example based on the following code
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/sql_taxi.py

I am getting an error message

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apache_beam/typehints/schemas.py in typing_to_runner_api(type_)
177         array_type=schema_pb2.ArrayType(element_type=element_type))
178
--> 179   raise ValueError("Unsupported type: %s" % type_)
180
181

ValueError: Unsupported type: Any

The corresponding part of the code is

> ```
>    mean_open_close = (
>    csv_lines |beam.Map(
>        lambda x: beam.Row(
>            element_date=x['Date'],
>            element_open=x['Open'],
>            element_close=x['Close']))
>    | SqlTransform(
>        """
>         SELECT
>           element_date,
>           AVERAGE(element_open) AS average_open,
>           AVERAGE(element_close) AS average_close
>         FROM PCOLLECTION""")
> ```
>
> )

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual code, it's unclear what the issue is (as the posted example works just fine), but going on a hunch I might guess that you're writing

```
beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(attr=expr, ...))
```

for some `expr` for which Beam is not able to infer the type. You could explicitly write this as

```
beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(attr=type(expr), ...))
```

Comment: adding type doesn't fix the issue. I added the code in the question

Comment: What exactly is the type in question? Currently only basic types are supported by schemas (for use in SQL).